# Suexec and chmod 711

Tags: apache, suexec

I'm curious to understand why Suexec does not permit a 711 permisson on files. In general, I always set the files in my cgi-bin dir to 711 not 755. Can someone explain to me the logic on why Suexec spits out an error into the Apache log files if you violate this permissions constraint? I'm setting up a VPS account for someone and I can't get around the Suexec error without setting all cgi/perl files to chmod 755. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: No idea why you'd want 711 instead of 700 or 755. You can't execute an "interpreted" program without read permission, so 711 makes no sense. As for why 755 is needed instead of 700, don't know.

Comment: 711 is more secure than 755 and I have plenty of production level scripts running with 711, not 755.

Comment: You appear to have not read what I wrote at all, since your comment has nothing to do with what I wrote. I said there's no reason to use 711 instead of 700 for Perl programs. They're equivalent, since you can't execute a Perl script without being able to read it.  So the actual question is why does suexec require 755 instead of 700. And I don't know.